# Format Date to long format

Tags: javascript, date

I am working in javascript and am trying to format a date that I am receiving in this format `2017-07-31` to this format `July 31, 2017`.

Is there a best practice on accomplishing this?

Comment: @AlexanderNied - true, but the accepted answer is old school :p

Comment: You can reformat a date string without conversion to a Date object (it's much easier and far less error prone).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An option with modern browsers (yes, including IE11 surprisingly) is to use Date#toLocaleString

```js
var dateString = "2017-07-31"; // you have a date string in this format
var date = new Date(dateString+'T00:00:00'); // force LOCAL time, 
// without the T00:00:00 the Date would be UTC
// and Western hemisphere dates will be a day out
options = {
    year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
};
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
// en-US, the only format that does Month Day, Year
```

If you are going to be doing a lot of dates, a more performant method is to use Intl.DateTimeFormat

```js
var dateString = "2017-07-31";
var date = new Date(dateString+'T00:00:00');
options = {
  year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
};

var fmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options);
// now use fmt.format(dateobject) as many times as you wish
console.log(fmt.format(date));
```

Comment: Fair enough, but this question has been asked a million times before. Maybe two million… The marked duplicates have 78 answers between them.

Comment: yes, but the ACCEPTED answer in the (only) duplicate others pointed out was 7 years old or something :p

Comment: I wouldn't use a Date at all, reformatting the string and replacing the month is two lines of code and completely avoids Date vagaries. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You should use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), it's very easy to format.

```
var dateStr = '2017-07-31';
var date = moment(dateStr, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
moment(date.format('MMMM Do, YYYY');
```

Comment: Your answer should not rely on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP.